# How to share a project so that more than 1 user can access and edit code in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, share

I have visual studio 2010 pro, and I need to be able to work side by side on the same project with another programmer who will also be running visual studio 2010. How can this be done the cheapest way?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have? One with MSDN included? If so, you already have license for the Team Foundation Server, that has a super integration into Visual Studio. Do will not get this kind of integration with SVN, Mercurial or GIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Suggest you to use Subversion for this.

You can get a free SVN server and easy to install like VisualSVN http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/

First yo install this server and then you have to install a client on the PCs (my suggestion is TortoiseSVN) http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

It takes some time to configure this, but you make it once and then you have the infraestructure for future projects. SVN is a one way trip...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "cheapest" literally, as in dollars or euros or whatever? Or do you mean "easiest"? Or what?

If you're talking monetary cost, the only legal way to do it is to buy two copies of Visual Studio, unless you're going to share a computer and only one work at a time.

If you mean "easiest", as in, you want to avoid stepping on each other's code changes, get a decent source code control system, like SVN. Then you check things in and out of the library and it helps keep changes straight. You can get SVN for free.